# What primary key to use from Google Identity JWT?

Tags: .net-6.0, google-identity

My front-end application successfully asked for authorization from the user, got a token from the Google API, sent it to an endpoint on my backend, and my .net app used the GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync to validate the token and provided the necessary information from the user.

I used that information to create a new `Account` record in my backend application.

However:

1. The description in the `Payload` class specifically says Email is not unique or suitable for a primary key. My regular user auth specifically uses an email+password setup, with the email address configured as a primary key through entity framework. If not email address, what would be the appropriate unique user identifier to tie their google account to my application account?
2. How do I log users into this (my application) account in the future? My initial assumption would have been "google email addresses are unique therefor it is safe to match future authorizations against that email address in my database" but as #1 points out, that's not true.

All the guides seem to just end right where I'm at, which makes me feel like the rest should be obvious and I'm <s>some sort of idiot</s> missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#an-id-tokens-payload) state that `sub` claim is an unique user id for google accounts:

| Claim | Provided | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub | always | An identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never reused. A Google account can have multiple email addresses at different points in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your application as the unique-identifier key for the user. Maximum length of 255 case-sensitive ASCII characters. |

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that.